# How to attach descriptions to properties and not objects in Spring Boot Swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

For a Spring Boot Swagger API Documentation project, I would like to be able to attach unique descriptions to properties of the same type. I have tried something like the code block below;

```
@Schema(name = "elm1", description = "elm1 description")
Element elm1;

@Schema(name = "elm2", description = "elm2 description")
Element elm2;

@Schema(name = "Element", description = "Element description")
public class Element {
    Element() { }
}
```

This seems to create something like this;

```
elm1:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Element'
elm2:
    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Element'
```

This leads the generated documentation giving only one description which is the same for every object of type 'Element'. This does not seem to be the case for types like 'String' or 'Double'. Is there a way to give each property a unique description, even if they are of the same Object class?

Edit: I have also tried adding a description to only the `elm1` and `elm2` and not the `Element` object. This does the same thing as above but will use one of the descriptions for all occurrences. For example, `elm1` and `elm2` will both have the `elm1` description.